# Typo3 v9 Show "hidden" pages in sitemap

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I am currently updating a website from Typo3 7 to Typo3 9. The Website includes a Sitemap, which I would like to also show pages that are marked as "Not in Menus". On the old version, this could be achieved usnig the following bit of typoscript:

```
tt_content.menu.20.2.includeNotInMenu = 1
tt_content.menu.20.2.excludeDoktypes = 6
```

This, however does not work anymore in v9 and I can't find any help on Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TYPO3 9 uses fluid_styled_content to render content instead of css_styled_content. The sitemap is rendered using a `MenuProcessor`. These same options are available in the `MenuProcessor`. You can set them using the following TypoScript:

```
tt_content.menu_sitemap.dataProcessing.10 {
  includeNotInMenu = 1
  excludeDoktypes = 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me. I am using Typo3 9.5.19
The following worked:

Add to constants

```
plugin.tx_seo.settings.xmlSitemap.sitemaps.pages.additionalWhere = no_index = 0 AND canonical_link = '' AND nav_hide = 0
```

Note: This does stop sub pages under a hidden page. all pages needs to be marked hidden